# How does code splitting actually work? (and how can I code split with django?)

Tags: javascript, django, webpack, code-splitting

I'm using Django to serve HTML files, with a react application inside one of them. The application is too large and I would like to implement code splitting. This is simple enough to do with webpack, which I get allows me to break up the application into smaller files. I can load the scripts in order in the HTML template, but doesn't this just mean they'll all be loaded one at a time HTML page is served?

How does webpack's code splitting actually determine which files are requested from the server, only at the points at which they're required by the user?

Also, does anyone know how to correctly React code splitting in this way with Django?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research - I think that the scripts are loaded via script tag injection by the 'runtime bundle' that webpack generates. In case anyone is wondering about how to load this with django - I've hacked together a little solution with Html webpack plugin and a custom django plugin to format it correctly in the Django template. Let me know if this would be useful to anyone.